# Identify all node parameters in a quick way

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to identify all parameters of a node in a quick way? Such as double click the wanted node on the graph frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can view all properties of a selected node in the Neo4j Browser:

[image]

If you are after the property keys, you can use the `keys` Cypher function to retrieve an array of property keys for a node:

```
MATCH (l:Legislator) RETURN keys(l) AS keys LIMIT 1
```

would return an array of strings:

```
[gender, type, religion, party, firstName, republicanCount, lastName, democratCount, fecIDs, birthday, currentParty, washpostID, icpsrID, state, cspanID, wikipediaID, otherCount, govtrackID, opensecretsID, votesmartID, bioguideID, thomasID, lisID]
```